# Excel VBA copy table from word to excel

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I am updating this post with update code.

```
Sub ImportWordTable()

Dim WordApp     As Object
Dim WordDoc     As Object
Dim arrFileList As Variant, FileName As Variant
Dim tableNo     As Integer        'table number in Word
Dim tableStart  As Integer
Dim tableTot    As Integer
Dim LastRow     As Long

LastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

'On Error Resume Next

arrFileList = Application.GetOpenFilename("Word files (*.doc; *.docx),*.doc;*.docx", 2, _
              "Browse For file containing table To be imported", , True)

If Not IsArray(arrFileList) Then Exit Sub        '(user cancelled import file browser)

Set WordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
WordApp.Visible = True

'Range("A:AZ").ClearContents

For Each FileName In arrFileList
    Set WordDoc = WordApp.Documents.Open(FileName, ReadOnly:=True)
    
    With WordDoc
        tableNo = WordDoc.tables.Count
        tableTot = WordDoc.tables.Count
        If tableNo = 0 Then
            MsgBox WordDoc.Name & " contains no tables", vbExclamation, "Import Word Table"
            
        ElseIf tableNo > 1 Then
            tableNo = InputBox(WordDoc.Name & " contains " & tableNo & " tables." & vbCrLf & _
                      "Enter the table To start from", "Import Word Table", "1")
        End If
        
        ' Set the header for the Colums

        With .tables(tableNo)
            Parent.Range("A" & LastRow).Value = .cell(1, 1).Range
            Parent.Range("B" & LastRow).Value = .cell(2, 1).Range
            Parent.Range("C" & LastRow).Value = .cell(3, 1).Range
            Parent.Range("D" & LastRow).Value = .cell(4, 1).Range
            Parent.Range("E" & LastRow).Value = .cell(5, 1).Range
            Parent.Range("F" & LastRow).Value = .cell(6, 1).Range
            Parent.Range("G" & LastRow).Value = .cell(7, 1).Range
            Parent.Range("H" & LastRow).Value = .cell(8, 1).Range
            Parent.Range("I" & LastRow).Value = .cell(9, 1).Range
            Parent.Range("J" & LastRow).Value = .cell(10, 1).Range
            Parent.Range("K" & LastRow).Value = .cell(11, 1).Range
            Parent.Range("L" & LastRow).Value = .cell(12, 1).Range
            Parent.Range("M" & LastRow).Value = .cell(13, 1).Range
            Parent.Range("N" & LastRow).Value = .cell(14, 1).Range
            Parent.Range("O" & LastRow).Value = .cell(15, 1).Range
            Parent.Range("P" & LastRow).Value = .cell(16, 1).Range
            Parent.Range("Q" & LastRow).Value = .cell(17, 1).Range
            Parent.Range("R" & LastRow).Value = .cell(18, 1).Range
            Parent.Range("S" & LastRow).Value = .cell(19, 1).Range
            Parent.Range("T" & LastRow).Value = .cell(20, 1).Range
            Parent.Range("U" & LastRow).Value = .cell(21, 1).Range
            Parent.Range("V" & LastRow).Value = .cell(22, 1).Range
            Parent.Range("W" & LastRow).Value = .cell(23, 1).Range
            Parent.Range("X" & LastRow).Value = .cell(24, 1).Range
            Parent.Range("Y" & LastRow).Value = .cell(25, 1).Range
            
        End With
        LastRow = LastRow + 1
        
        ' Get the date from the tables
        For tableStart = tableNo To tableTot
        
            With .tables(tableStart)
            .cell(1, 2).Range.Copy
            With Range("A" & LastRow)
                .Select
                .Parent.PasteSpecial Format:="HTML", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False
                .Borders.LineStyle = xlLineStyleNone
            End With
            
            .cell(2, 2).Range.Copy
            With Range("B" & LastRow)
                .Select
                .Parent.PasteSpecial Format:="HTML", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False
                .Borders.LineStyle = xlLineStyleNone
            End With
            
            .cell(3, 2).Range.Copy
            With Range("C" & LastRow)
                .Select
                .Parent.PasteSpecial Format:="HTML", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False
                .Borders.LineStyle = xlLineStyleNone
            End With
            
            .cell(4, 2).Range.Copy
            With Range("D" & LastRow)
                .Select
                .Parent.PasteSpecial Format:="HTML", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False
                .Borders.LineStyle = xlLineStyleNone
            End With
            .cell(5, 2).Range.Copy
            With Range("E" & LastRow)
                .Select
                .Parent.PasteSpecial Format:="HTML", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False
                .Borders.LineStyle = xlLineStyleNone
            End With
            .cell(6, 2).Range.Copy
            With Range("F" & LastRow)
                .Select
                .Parent.PasteSpecial Format:="HTML", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False
                .Borders.LineStyle = xlLineStyleNone
            End With
            .cell(7, 2).Range.Copy
            With Range("G" & LastRow)
                .Select
                .Parent.PasteSpecial Format:="HTML", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False
                .Borders.LineStyle = xlLineStyleNone
            End With
            .cell(8, 2).Range.Copy
            With Range("H" & LastRow)
                .Select
                .Parent.PasteSpecial Format:="HTML", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False
                .Borders.LineStyle = xlLineStyleNone
            End With
            .cell(9, 2).Range.Copy
            With Range("I" & LastRow)
                .Select
                .Parent.PasteSpecial Format:="HTML", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False
                .Borders.LineStyle = xlLineStyleNone
            End With
            .cell(10, 2).Range.Copy
            With Range("J" & LastRow)
                .Select
                .Parent.PasteSpecial Format:="HTML", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False
                .Borders.LineStyle = xlLineStyleNone
            End With
            .cell(11, 2).Range.Copy
            With Range("K" & LastRow)
                .Select
                .Parent.PasteSpecial Format:="HTML", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False
                .Borders.LineStyle = xlLineStyleNone
            End With
            .cell(12, 2).Range.Copy
            With Range("L" & LastRow)
                .Select
                .Parent.PasteSpecial Format:="HTML", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False
                .Borders.LineStyle = xlLineStyleNone
            End With
            .cell(13, 2).Range.Copy
            With Range("M" & LastRow)
                .Select
                .Parent.PasteSpecial Format:="HTML", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False
                .Borders.LineStyle = xlLineStyleNone
            End With
            .cell(14, 2).Range.Copy
            With Range("N" & LastRow)
                .Select
                .Parent.PasteSpecial Format:="HTML", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False
                .Borders.LineStyle = xlLineStyleNone
            End With
            .cell(15, 2).Range.Copy
            With Range("O" & LastRow)
                .Select
                .Parent.PasteSpecial Format:="HTML", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False
                .Borders.LineStyle = xlLineStyleNone
            End With
            .cell(16, 2).Range.Copy
            With Range("P" & LastRow)
                .Select
                .Parent.PasteSpecial Format:="HTML", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False
                .Borders.LineStyle = xlLineStyleNone
            End With
            .cell(17, 2).Range.Copy
            With Range("Q" & LastRow)
                .Select
                .Parent.PasteSpecial Format:="HTML", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False
                .Borders.LineStyle = xlLineStyleNone
            End With
            .cell(18, 2).Range.Copy
            With Range("R" & LastRow)
                .Select
                .Parent.PasteSpecial Format:="HTML", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False
                .Borders.LineStyle = xlLineStyleNone
            End With
            .cell(19, 2).Range.Copy
            With Range("S" & LastRow)
                .Select
                .Parent.PasteSpecial Format:="HTML", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False
                .Borders.LineStyle = xlLineStyleNone
            End With
            .cell(20, 2).Range.Copy
            With Range("T" & LastRow)
                .Select
                .Parent.PasteSpecial Format:="HTML", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False
                .Borders.LineStyle = xlLineStyleNone
            End With
            .cell(21, 2).Range.Copy
            With Range("U" & LastRow)
                .Select
                .Parent.PasteSpecial Format:="HTML", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False
                .Borders.LineStyle = xlLineStyleNone
            End With
            .cell(22, 2).Range.Copy
            With Range("V" & LastRow)
                .Select
                .Parent.PasteSpecial Format:="HTML", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False
                .Borders.LineStyle = xlLineStyleNone
            End With
            .cell(23, 2).Range.Copy
            With Range("W" & LastRow)
                .Select
                .Parent.PasteSpecial Format:="HTML", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False
                .Borders.LineStyle = xlLineStyleNone
            End With
            .cell(24, 2).Range.Copy
            With Range("X" & LastRow)
                .Select
                .Parent.PasteSpecial Format:="HTML", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False
                .Borders.LineStyle = xlLineStyleNone
            End With
            .cell(25, 2).Range.Copy
            With Range("Y" & LastRow)
                .Select
                .Parent.PasteSpecial Format:="HTML", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False
                .Borders.LineStyle = xlLineStyleNone
            End With
            
            End With
            
            LastRow = LastRow + 1
            
        Next tableStart
        
        .Close False
    End With
    
Next FileName

WordApp.Quit

Set WordDoc = Nothing
Set WordApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

It is working but having only one issue. if a cell is having multiple paragraph then it's getting pasted in multiple row of excel. I want like if 2nd column of 1st row of word file is having 3 paragraph, then in excel as well all these 3 paragraph should get pasted in same column.
Word Input
[image: Word File Input]

Excel File Output
[image: Output file]

Hope I am able to explain it properly.

Comment: Unfortunately, Word VBA does not have a `Range` property for a column. What you need can be efficiently done in two ways: Selecting the column in discussion (which is admitted) and copy it, and more efficient if you do not care about the format, place the column content in an array and drop the array content in the place you need.  Eventually, to copy the format after that. If interested, I can show you how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

I have amended your script to produce the desired results.

- The clear contents and targeting is removed as this will allow other word tables to be added to the same sheet, amend the script if you want to clear the sheet each time.
- The table start selection now works by setting the `tableNo` as the start of the loop
- It pulls the heading from the first column of the first selected `tableNo`

VBA Script:

```
Sub ImportWordTable()

Dim WordApp     As Object
Dim WordDoc     As Object
Dim arrFileList As Variant, FileName As Variant
Dim tableNo     As Integer        'table number in Word
Dim tableStart  As Integer
Dim tableTot    As Integer
Dim LastRow     As Long

LastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

'On Error Resume Next

arrFileList = Application.GetOpenFilename("Word files (*.doc; *.docx),*.doc;*.docx", 2, _
              "Browse For file containing table To be imported", , True)

If Not IsArray(arrFileList) Then Exit Sub        '(user cancelled import file browser)

Set WordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
WordApp.Visible = True

'Range("A:AZ").ClearContents

For Each FileName In arrFileList
    Set WordDoc = WordApp.Documents.Open(FileName, ReadOnly:=True)
    
    With WordDoc
        tableNo = WordDoc.tables.Count
        tableTot = WordDoc.tables.Count
        If tableNo = 0 Then
            MsgBox WordDoc.Name & " contains no tables", vbExclamation, "Import Word Table"
            
        ElseIf tableNo > 1 Then
            tableNo = InputBox(WordDoc.Name & " contains " & tableNo & " tables." & vbCrLf & _
                      "Enter the table To start from", "Import Word Table", "1")
        End If
        
        ' Set the header for the Colums

        With .tables(tableNo)
            Parent.Range("A" & LastRow).Value = .Cell(1, 1).Range
            Parent.Range("B" & LastRow).Value = .Cell(2, 1).Range
            Parent.Range("C" & LastRow).Value = .Cell(3, 1).Range
        End With
        LastRow = LastRow + 1
        
        ' Get the date from the tables
        For tableStart = tableNo To tableTot
        
            With .tables(tableStart)
            
            .Cell(1, 2).Range.Copy
            With Range("A" & LastRow)
                .Select
                .Parent.PasteSpecial Format:="HTML", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False
                .Borders.LineStyle = xlLineStyleNone
            End With
            
            .Cell(2, 2).Range.Copy
            With Range("B" & LastRow)
                .Select
                .Parent.PasteSpecial Format:="HTML", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False
                .Borders.LineStyle = xlLineStyleNone
            End With
            
            .Cell(3, 2).Range.Copy
            With Range("C" & LastRow)
                .Select
                .Parent.PasteSpecial Format:="HTML", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False
                .Borders.LineStyle = xlLineStyleNone
            End With
            
            End With
            
            LastRow = LastRow + 1
            
        Next tableStart
        
        .Close False
    End With
    
Next FileName

WordApp.Quit

Set WordDoc = Nothing
Set WordApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: I tried this and modified as well but challenge I am facing with any cell is having multiple paragraph or any image then it always copy in different row. And randomly it gives error but when I execute one by one line then it works fine.

Comment: Stepping through the code should produce the same results as running the script. In the word document, are the images and paragraphs outside or within the table? Update your post with your newly modified code, place it at the bottom leaving your original code there. Also post screen shots of the word file and also the unexpected results in the excel document.

Comment: Used same code, I have updated question with new screenshot. I was not getting option here in comments.

Comment: I tried with the updated code but my challenge is still there. I have updated my original post with input word and output excel. In word there are multiple paragraph in cells. Everything is working as expected but only challenge with multiple paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

As I said in my above comment, one Word table column cannot copy directly, not having a range property. Two ways are recommended, to avoid copying of each table cell, which consumes Excel resources and is very slow. One way would be to select the respective column (VBA allows it) and copy/paste selection. But using clipboard it is slow for more involved documents.

The most efficient way is to place the column range in an array (working only in memory) and drop its content, at once, in the necessary range. Then, try to format it. Copying the format from Word is also slow and consumes resources. I used a trick: Transforming the dropped array content range in an `listObject`, then `UnList` it. To benefit of the standard table format. If you need them to be tables, you have to comment the code line `tbl.UnList`:

```
Sub ImportWordTable()
    Dim WordApp As Object, WordDoc As Object, ws As Worksheet
    Dim arrFileList As Variant, FileName As Variant, tableNo As Integer
    Dim tableStart As Integer, tableTot As Integer, Target As Range
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet 'it is good to fully qualify all the objects
                         'so, use here the sheet you need
                                          
    arrFileList = Application.GetOpenFilename("Word files (*.doc; *.docx),*.doc;*.docx", 2, _
        "Browse for file containing table to be imported", , True)

    If Not IsArray(arrFileList) Then Exit Sub '(user cancelled import file browser)

    Set WordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    
    WordApp.Visible = True

    ws.Range("A:A").Clear 'clear its format, too...
    Set Target = ws.Range("A1")
    
    Dim i As Long, tbl As ListObject
    For Each FileName In arrFileList
        Set WordDoc = WordApp.Documents.Open(FileName, ReadOnly:=True)
        With WordDoc
            tableNo = WordDoc.tables.count
            tableTot = WordDoc.tables.count
            If tableNo = 0 Then
                MsgBox WordDoc.name & " contains no tables", vbExclamation, "Import Word Table"

            ElseIf tableNo > 1 Then
                tableNo = InputBox(WordDoc.name & " contains " & tableNo & " tables." & vbCrLf & _
                  "Enter the table to start from", "Import Word Table", "1")
            End If
            
            For tableStart = tableNo To tableTot 'start iteration from `tableNo` if not the default...
                Dim arr: ReDim arr(1 To .tables(tableStart).rows.count, 1 To 1) 'declare and ReDim the necessary aray
                With .tables(tableStart)
                    For i = 1 To .rows.count 'load the array with the second column content
                        arr(i, 1) = .Range.Columns(2).cells(i)
                        arr(i, 1) = left(arr(i, 1), Len(arr(i, 1)) - 1) 'eliminate the Word strange ending line character
                    Next i
                    With Target.Resize(.rows.count, 1)
                        .Value = arr
                        Set tbl = ws.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, ws.Range(.address), , xlYes) 'make the range a table
                        tbl.Unlist  'just transforming the table in range, but keeping its format...
                    End With
                    Set Target = Target.Offset(.Rows.Count + 2) 'reset Target
                End With
                
            Next tableStart
            

            .Close False 'close the open document, without saving it
        End With
    Next FileName

    WordApp.Quit

    Set WordDoc = Nothing: Set WordApp = Nothing
    
End Sub
```

Comment: @Rajeev Kumar For some seconds I could see a comment saying something about a highlighted code line... If so and not from another question, do not hesitate to ask for clarifications. This is the best way of learning...

Comment: Updated my question, i have tried your code as well but it give me error on this line "Set Target = Target.Offset(.Rows.Count + 2) 'reset Target"
Also, it only copying column wise not row wise.

Comment: @Rajeev Kumar You should tell me about it... Please, test the updated code. The respective line should be placed two rows above. I edited the answer and placed it where it should be. I cannot see anything new in your updated question...

Comment: Please check my post I have updated with screenshot.

Comment: @Rajeev Kumar Ups... I said to placed the code line to rows above, but I moved  it only one (excepting `End With`). Please, test the adapted code. It should work now. I did not test the code for more than a table and commented that line, not being of interest for mai test (I thought)...